# Re-authenticate failed Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create *Change Password* feature... but I don't know why getting the error, although I type the correct password. It's always returning *failed*.

I follow this code from
[Manager Users Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)

and this is my code

```
edtOldPass = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.edt_oldpass);

mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String email = mCurrentUser.getEmail();
            String pass = edtOldPass.getEditText().toString();

            AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, pass);

            mCurrentUser.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Intent newpassIntent = new Intent(ReAuthActivity.this, ChangePassActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newpassIntent);

                    } else {                       
                        Toast.makeText(ReAuthActivity.this, "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code to get the password is not correct:

```
String pass = edtOldPass.getEditText().toString();
```

Calling [getEditText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#getEditText()) on a `TextInputLayout` returns the contained `EditText` widget, not the string value of the `EditText`.

Change it to this:

```
String pass = edtOldPass.getEditText().getText().toString();
```